# reload app from AppDelegate.m with phonegap

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I'm developing an app using jquerymobile and phonegap.

I was wondering is there a way to reload an app using

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIWebView*) theWebView  { 
  //reload here 
  } 
  or
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application { 
  //reload here 
  }

using objective c in AppDelegate.m

and not the onresume phonegap event.

????

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, try calling;

```
[self.viewController.webView reload];
```